In IOS mobile app technology is React native, locators are merged with all the elements in a single page
IOS locators 1
IOS locators 2
In above image elements are merged in all properties, whether this issue would be handled  from developer's side.
which properties need to be added to overcome this issue,tried inspecting locators in appium inspector also.
